# UIImageView size changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have navigation bar with custom view on it. UIImageView and UILabel are subviews of titleView. And I add UITapGestureRecognizer to titleView to make it show another UIViewController when the user taps on it. When you tap on titleView other UIViewController opens. But when you click on back button in my titleView size of UIImageView changes. Here is the code

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
title.text = _groupName;
[title setTextColor:[self colorFromHexString:@"#474747"]];
[title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:16]];
[title setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
_imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
_imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
_imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
title.frame = CGRectMake(title.frame.origin.x+20, title.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30);
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(titleTapped:)];
titleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[titleView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[titleView addSubview:title];
[titleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[titleView addSubview:_imageView];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Here are the images where you can see the changes
[image: navigationBar]

[image: newViewController]

[image: after back]

Answer (score 0):

I check your code Add clips to bounds and do not need to title frame two times.

```
_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
_imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
_imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_imageView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the frame of the views directly, you might try using [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/); I suspect what's happening is that your custom view is getting re-layed-out after the back button, and it's reverting to the image view's `instrinsicSize`.

What you could do instead is turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the subviews, and then add constraints to position them, and finally add width and height constraints to the image view.

Using Auto Layout is also recommended if you ever intend to internationalize your app -- if you set up your constraints correctly, then the translated title will fit and you won't have to ever play around with hardcoded values.